# Cannot establish connection with socket.io (xhr poll error) in FireFox

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, socket.io

I am using socket.io 1.4.8 and firefox 48. I have a sample code that works fine in chrome:

```
// Server
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); var fs = require('fs');
var option = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};
var https = require('https').createServer(options, app).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
var io = require('socket.io')(https);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('login', function(username) {
        console.log('[login]', username);
    };
}

// Client
var socket = io('https://127.0.0.1:3000');
var username = 'test';
socket.emit('login', username);
```

But when i run in firefox, i got an `Error: xhr poll error.` Here is the log from client:

```
socket.io-client:url "parse https://127.0.0.1:3000" +0ms
socket.io-client "new io instance for https://127.0.0.1:3000" +3ms
socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +3ms
socket.io-client:manager "opening https://127.0.0.1:3000" +1ms
engine.io-client:socket creating transport "polling" +1ms
engine.io-client:polling polling +1ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +2ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr "xhr open GET: https://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LTvQYL3" +1ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +1ms
engine.io-client:socket setting transport polling +2ms
socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 8000 +1ms
socket.io-client:manager readyState opening +3ms
engine.io-client:socket socket error {"type":"TransportError","description":0} +74ms
socket.io-client:manager connect_error +1ms
socket.io-client:manager cleanup +0ms
```

How can i fix this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason was site's self-signed certificate not being trusted by Firefox. Go to socket url and you should be shown a dialog to add the untrusted site to exceptions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)